# displaytag table column totals

Tags: html, jsp, html-table, displaytag

I'm using the [displaytag](http://displaytag.homeip.net/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-columnsummation.jsp) JSP tag library to generate tables that show column totals. For example in the JSP code below, only those columns with the attribute `total="true"` will have totals generated.

```
<display:table name="myTable" id="myTable" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator">
    <display:column property="name" title="Name" />
    <display:column property="description" title="Description" />

    <display:column property="openCount" title="Opened" total="true"/>
    <display:column property="revenueTotal" title="Commission" total="true"/>
</display:table>
```

The problem is that displaytag places these totals in the final  `<tr>` in the table body, but I need them to be inside the table footer  `<tfoot>` instead. Is this possible without post-processing the generated HTML in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [display:footer](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html#footer) (which is how the example @tvanfosson referenced works)